# How to compare two temporally-distinct but otherwise identical tables in BigQuery/SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables, curr and prev. Every day, curr is copied to prev and becomes the new prev. Then, curr is updated from an external source. The tables have the same schema. I"m using the BQ flavour of SQL.

The rough layout of the tables is a primary email as the unique key and then the record of a subscription. The same user (as identified by primary email) may have multiple subscriptions historically, although only one subscription will be currently active. Fields include things like subscription start date, subscription amount, cancellation status etc.

I am looking to SELECT only the differences between the two tables i.e. only the records which have recently changed their e.g. start date, amount, or cancellation status.

However, I'm struggling. I've tried SELECTing DISTINCT from the two tables joined where curr.start_date!=prev.start_date (OR any of the other fields of interest), but its just giving me the people who have previously held more than one subscription. There may be a way to return only the latest subscription using PARTITION BY and ROW ORDER but I'm not sure how to do this.

I've also tried SELECT* FROM curr EXCEPT DISTINCT SELECT* FROM prev, but I think this is only giving me new- rather than updated- rows.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance.

Some tabular data- both curr and prev look like this. In the case of an update, a new entry is created in curr, with the Primary_Email remaining the same.

| primary_email | start_date | status | cancellation_type | amount | frequency | bundle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mickey.mouse@gmail.com | 2020-10-14 | Active | Active | 300 | monthly | a |
| Minnie.mouse@gmail.com | 2021-01-12 | Cancelled | Pre-start | 12 | monthly | b |
| Roger.rabbit@gmail.com | 2019-08-14 | Failure | Post-start | 25 | annually | b |
| John.doe@gmail.com | 2020-04-24 | Active | Active | 555 | monthly | a |
| Jane.doe@gmail.com | 2021-02-12 | Failure | Post-start | 15 | annually | c |

My desired output is the same table (those fields from curr), but only the rows which are present in curr but not in prev.

Comment: Please share some sample in tabular format. Input tables and desired result.

Comment: Some sample data and desired result would be helpful, but a good place to start would be a `full outer join` on columns of interest. That way you can see the difference in tables side by side and it will give you a good idea of what to look for next.

Comment: Done- many thanks for your help. I have tried an outer join which I think is getting me closer, but the problem I have is that because some primary_emails have multiple entries in curr, I am getting returned those rows rather than those which only exist in curr and not in prev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were close. You could just add conditions to each of your `select` to make sure you only consider email addresses that are shared across both tables.

```
select * 
from curr 
where email in (select email from prev)

except 

select * 
from prev
where email in (select email from curr)
```

Comment: With the addition of a DISTINCT after EXCEPT (required by BQ), I think that may have done the trick- hard to tell with my crappy understanding of the way in which `curr` is updated. Many thanks for your help!